# Measure on Hilbert Space

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

On $\mathbb{R}^n$, we of course have the usual Lebesgue meausre.  In many ways, separable, infinite-dimesional Hilbert space is the most natural generalization of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to infinite-dimensions, so it is natural to ask, does there exist a Lebesgue-like measure on separable, infinite dimensional Hilbert space?  For the sake of concreteness, is there a natural, Lebesgue-like measure on $\ell ^2$?  (For this purposes of this question, I don't believe it should make a difference whether we are working over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.)

Comment: What do you mean by "natural, Lebesgue-like"? Translation-invariant Borel measure? If so, then there's a theorem of Mackey and Weil telling you that if such a measure exists on a separable completely metrizable group then the group must be locally compact. So if you want such a measure to exist on a Hilbert space, it must be finite-dimensional.

Comment: @t.b. Yes, at the very least it should a translation-invariant Borel measure.  This is essentially a solution then.  Can you point me to reference I can find this theorem in?

Comment: Maybe this [thread here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44324/) and [this thread on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36403/) contain further pointers of interest. **Edit:** I didn't see your comment before posting this one. I'll look for a reference.

Comment: Lebesgue measure is not only translation-invariant, it satisfies $\mu(\lambda A) = \lambda^n \mu(A)$ for real $\lambda \ge 0$, and I don't see a reasonable way to generalize this to an infinite-dimensional space.

Comment: Okay, it's always a bit hard to find a reference for these folklore results. The only essentially self-contained one I know of is [Theorem 5.41](http://books.google.com/books?id=AbbMLuXC9tsC&pg=PA200) in Varadarajan's *[Geometry of quantum theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=AbbMLuXC9tsC)*, Springer, 1973.

Comment: Is it really possible that none of the linked references contain a pointer to Problem 18 in Halmos' *A Hilbert space problem book*?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As clarified, you are looking for translation-invariant Borel measures.  Here are two: the zero measure, and counting measure.  Obviously those are not going to satisfy you, but you can't really do better.

> **Theorem.** A translation-invariant Borel measure on an infinite-dimensional separable Banach space is either the zero measure, or assigns infinite measure to every open set.

You can find a proof on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_dimensional_Lebesgue_measure), or in Theorem 1.1 of [these notes I wrote](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.03591).

Comment: Is the parenthetical in Exercise 1.2 meant to be easily answerable or just thought provoking? `:-)` Finding a counterexample may not be entirely straight forward.

Comment: @WillieWong: It was more a question for myself.  I don't know the answer, but I wish I did.

Comment: dunno if you've seen [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61610/measures-on-infinite-dimensional-banach-spaces/65982#65982). The answer to your question is apparently independent of ZF + DC!

Comment: Theorem presented by Nate Eldredge admits the following extension:                                                      {\bf Theorem.}  Any Borel measure on an infinite-dimensional separable Banach space, which is invariant with respect to everywhere dense vector subspace,  is either the zero measure, or assigns infinite measure to every open set.

Answer (score 10):

The following facts are valid:

**Fact 1.** *There exists  a  sigma-finite Borel measure in $\ell_2$ which is invariant under the group of all eventually zero sequences and takes the value $1$ on the Hilbert cube $\prod_{k \in N}[0,\frac{1}{k}]$.*

The proof of Fact 1 can be found in [Kharazishvili A.B., On invariant measures in the Hilbert space.Bull. Acad. Sci.Georgian SSR, 114(1) (1984),41--48 (in Russian)].

**Fact 2.** *There exists  a translation-invariant Borel measure  $\mu$ in $\ell_2$ which  takes the  value $1$ on the Hilbert cube $\prod_{k \in N}[0,\frac{1}{k}]$.*

The proof of Fact 2 can be obtained by Baker measure $\lambda$ [Baker R.,  ``Lebesgue measure" on $\mathbb{R}^{ \infty}$. II. \textit{Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.} vol. 132, no. 9, 2003, pp. 2577--2591] as follows:

Let $T:\ell_2 \to \mathbb{R}^{ \infty}$ be defined by $T((x_k)_{k \in N})=(k x_k)_{k \in N}$ for $(x_k)_{k \in N} \in \ell_2$. For each Borel subset $X \subseteq \ell_2$ we set $\mu(X)=\lambda(T(X))$. Then $\mu$ satisfies all conditions of Fact 2.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 5):

Some authors take local compactness of the space to be part of the definition of Borel measure, so that leaves out infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces right away.  I think the Mackey-Weil result is talking about $\sigma$-finite measures.  If you don't require that, you might consider $r$-dimensional Hausdorff measure for any nonnegative real $r$.  These are translation-invariant measures, and all Borel sets are measurable.

Comment: I have the following questions:                          Question1. Does there exists an r-dimensional Hausdorf measure which takes the value 1 on Hilbert cube for some non-negative $r$? Question 2. Please, indicate a Borel set $F_r \subseteq l_2$ on which $r$-dimensional Hausdorf measure takes the vaslue 1?

Comment: I have the following questions:                             Question1. Does there exists an r-dimensional Hausdorf measure which takes the value 1 on Hilbert cube for some non-negative $r$?                                                     Question 2. Please, indicate a Borel set $F_r \subseteq l_2$ on which $r$-dimensional Hausdorf measure takes the value 1?

Comment: 1) No, the $r$-dimensional Hausdorff measure of any set of dimension greater than $r$ is infinite.  The Hilbert cube has $d$-dimensional subspaces for every finite $d$.
2) If $r$ is a positive integer, $F_r = \{x: 0 \le x_j \le 1 \text{ for }1 \le j \le r, x_j = 0 \text{ otherwise}\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Are you agree with me that a translation invariant Borel measure in $\ell_2$ which takes a numerical value $1$ on the Hilbert cube is not Hausdorf measure? Am I correct in my estimate?

Comment: Yes, of course.  Note, btw, that $\ell_2$ contains uncountably many disjoint translations of the Hilbert cube, so your measure is not $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: For each positive integer $r$, each $r$-dimensional Hausdorf measure in $\ell_2$, like the measure $\mu$ constructed above is non-$\sigma$-finite because $\ell_2$ contains uncountably many disjoint translations of the set $F_r$.

Comment: Note that $\mu$-measure of each finite-dimensional linear subspace of $\ell_2$ has $\mu$-measure zero. Can the measure $\mu$ considered as an infinite-dimensional version of the Hausdorf measure in $\ell_2$?

Answer (score 1):

Below I present a new construction of translation-invariant measures in a separable Banach space $B$ with the Schauder basis $(e_k)_{k \in N}$. We say that a Borel measure $\mu$ in $B$ is generator of shy sets(equivalently, Haar null sets) if the condition $\mu(X)=0$ implies that $X$ is shy(equivalently, Haar null).

**Definition 1.** *A universal measurable set $S$ in a
separable Banach space $B$ is said to be an $n$-dimensional
Preiss-Ti$\check{s}$er null set if every Lebesgue measure $\mu$
concentrated on any $n$-dimensional vector space $\Gamma$ is
transverse to $S$.*

We denote the class of all n-dimensional Preiss-Ti$\check{s}$er
null sets in $B$  by $$\mathcal{P~T~N}(B, n).$$

Let $(\Gamma_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of all $n$-dimensional
vector spaces and let $\mu_i$ be an $n$-dimensional Lebesgue
 measure concentrated on $\Gamma_i$  for $i \in I.$

Let $\Gamma_i^{\perp}$ be a linear complement of the vector space
$\Gamma_i$ for $i \in  I$. We put
$$
(\forall X)(X \in  \mathcal{B}(B) \rightarrow
G_{P~\&~T}^{(n)}(X)=\sum_{i \in I }\sum_{g \in
\Gamma_i^{\perp}}\mu_i(X-g \cap \Gamma_i)).
$$

**Theorem 1.** *A functional $G_{P~\&~T}^{(n)}$ is a
translation-invariant quasi-finite generator of shy sets  in $B$ such that
$$\mathcal{P~T~N}(B, n)=\mathcal{N}(\overline{G_{P~\&~T}^{(n)}}).$$*

**Remark 1.** The proof of Theorem 1 can be found in [G.Pantsulaia , On generators of shy sets on  Polish topological vector spaces, New  York   J.  Math.,14 ( 2008) ,  235 – 261].