# An example of a measure on $L^2(\Omega)$

Tags: measure-theory

Outside of the zero measure and counting measure, what are some examples of of measures over the space $L^2(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is some subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?  Mostly, I'm looking for concrete examples of measures in infinite dimensional space outside of stochastic measures like the Gaussian measure.  Certainly, as this question answered:

[Measure on Hilbert Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75932/measure-on-hilbert-space)

there's not a Lebesgue-like measure.  I'm really just looking for a combination of both simple and moderately interesting examples.

Comment: The Hilbert cube $\{x\in \ell^2\colon |x_i|\le 1/i\}$ supports a product measure (product of linear measures on each edge of the cube). You can move this into $L^2$ by Fourier transform to produce something exotic-looking.